# "Broken-line paths" in $\mathbb R^n - \{ 0 \}$

Tags: general-topology, terminology

In Munkres's *Topology*, he says:

> Suppose $x$ and $y$ are two different points from zero of the punctured euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n -\{0\}$. We can join them a path by the straight-line path between them if that path doesn't go through the origin. Otherwise, we can choose a point $z$ not on the line joining $x$ and $y$ and take the *broken-line path* from $x$ to $z$ and then from $z$ and $y$.

I don't understand this so-called ***broken-line path***. What is that? How can we define this function in terms of the path from $x$ to $z$ and the path from $z$ to $y$?

By the *straight-line path* he means, the path $f$ of any two points $x$ and $y$ of the unit ball $B^n$ of $\mathbb{R}$ where:
$$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \text{ and } f(t)=(1-t)x+ty.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically defined by $$f(t)=\begin{cases} (1-2t)x+2tz & t\in[0,.5] \\ (1-(2t-1))z+(2t-1)y & t\in(.5,1] \end{cases}$$
That is, it's just the straight line from $x$ to $z$ followed by the straight line from $z$ to $y$.

(Source: Munkres did this in lecture.)

Comment: Great source haha!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(2t-1)$ instrad of  $2t+1$? So it's true that $f(1)= y$. If it's $2t+1$, it's not true that $f(1)= y$

Comment: @MathsLover Yes, perfectly right, I'll fix that.